# Android ExpandableListActivity Change View at runtime

Tags: android, expandable

I am using `ExpandableListActivity` i am using

```
SimpleExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> groupData, int groupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> childData, int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo);
```

for my activity.
    Here i have created Context Menu. Using Context Menu i am deleting the value from database and also form `ArrayList` of `Child Group`.
    I am getting problem is i want to update my `ChildView` of Expandable List Activity immediately after deleting values From `DataBase` and `ArrayList.`
i tried using `notifyDataSetChanged()`. It do not work as because i am not deleting the value from ExpandableListAdapter itself. I also tried by calling Adapter again after deleting values but it gives two listviews.

```
// here on select ContextMenu
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
// Getting positions of Group and child from Expandable ListView
        int groupPos = 0, childPos = 0;
        int type = ExpandableListView
                .getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
        if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
            groupPos = ExpandableListView
                    .getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);
            childPos = ExpandableListView
                    .getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);
        }

        db.openConnection(this);

        View v = info.targetView;
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grp_child);
        String string = (String) tv.getText();
// Here I delete the value from DataBase onClik of Context Menu.
        if (item.getItemId() == 0) {
            final String where = "title=?";
            final String[] args = new String[] { string };
            database.delete(tableData, where, args);
        }
// Here I delete the value from ArrayList onClik of Context Menu.
//result1 is ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>();
        result1.get(groupPos).get(childPos);
        result1.remove(result1.get(groupPos).get(childPos));
        Log.e("Search", "is" + result1.get(groupPos).get(childPos));

        /*expListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/
        db.closeConnection();
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
// when i delete form both arraylist and database i want to update //ListView immidiately.
    }
```

Any Help will be appricited.

Thanks in Advance..

Mahaveer

Comment: Show your code what you are trying.

Comment: No, you can post your code here.

Comment: i had edited my post. Thanks suri.

Comment: i had also added comments for your convinience.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463906/how-to-update-expandable-list-view-when-adapters-data-changes

Comment: Thanks For Help suri sahani.. but that example do not works in my case.. thanks.